# TestNG one test for two classes

Tags: java, testng

I have TestNG tests in some classes, which extends the same main class. 
I need the same last test for class1 and class2, but if I add `@Test(priority = 666)` to main class it start after all classes.
How I should annotate `@Test` in main class what would it starts after all tests of each class?

Big thanks. Also sorry for bad english.

main class

```
    public class MainTest {

    @BeforeClass()
    public void setup() {
    //something 
    }

    @AfterClass()
    public void tearDown() {
    //something
    }

    @AfterMethod()
    public void log_writer(Method method) {
    //something
           }

    @Test(priority = 666) {}
    }
```

class1

```
    public class Class1 extends MainTest {

    @Test
    public void test1(){}

    @Test
    public void test2(){}  

    }
```

and class2

```
    public class Class2 extends MainTest {

    @Test
    public void test1(){}

    @Test
    public void test2(){}  
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need tests to be dependent on order of execution? Ideally you should write tests which are independent from each other, so that they can be executed in parallel.

Comment: I know. But in this test i want to check logs, maked while others tests pass.

Comment: In that case, can you break down your "log checking" test and put it in respective class, so that it will check the logs created in the same class?
I am assuming you can assign priorities to the tests within a class.

Comment: Yes, but then the same code will be repeated several times. I was hoping to do without it. Actually i have about 30 test classes.

Comment: I would use TestNG dependencies instead of mucking about with priorities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Basically each `@Test` runs only once. If you need to do something after each test class you have to use `@AfterClass` annotation on method in your `MainTest`. You can do some hacks with method order etc. in MethodInterceptor (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) but it's not good idea for this case.

Comment: In TestNG you don't need hacks, you can simply specify dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is the @AfterClass annotation. handle the part where you want to check logs in the AfterClass annotated method

Comment: Are you asking to run a *test* in @AfterClass method? I am not sure if that's a good idea.

Comment: I agree that its not a good idea to run a test in @AfterClass, But if the intention is to collect the logs after each class is run that serves the purpose.

Comment: I see. The way I understood the question, I though OP needs to check if the logs are generated (or contents of the log), and fail the test if they are not, instead of just seeing the logs manually.

Comment: @Garbage, Yes. in AfterMethod I write logs in array and iwant to check this array in last test for each class. After read answers, i think, beter write all logs of all classes in one big file, and check logs after all tests.